# Why does bash/echo do strange things using brackets? Maybe a bug

Tags: linux, bash

```
# ls -l
insgesamt 0
# echo [a]
[a]
# > a
# echo [a]
a
```

Things have changed, no more brackets, cause of existing file "a" ... Why???

Comment: That's because arguments are subject to pathname expansion which includes pattern matching (see `man bash` for details).

Comment: In such cases, it often helps to perform a little probability analysis. What do you think is more likely: that, among the millions of users of bash, *you* are the *only one* smart enough to find a bug in a piece of functionality that is used probably hundreds of millions of times every single day … or that it is maybe not a bug, but you just misread the documentation? Note: I am not saying that widely-used tools don't have bugs. They do.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a bug. It is, in fact, as intended.

Some characters have a special meaning in `bash`. the `[` and `]` are examples, but `*` is another. They are used for expansion. The `[` and `]` are used for 'any character between the two brackets. So, `[abcd]` will match `a` as well. If the expansion fails, the string is presented as-is as argument to the command, in your case `echo`.

In the empty directory, `[a]` fails to expand, and is therefore given unmodified as argument to `echo`. When you created `a` with `>a`, the expansion now succeeds, and the argument is therefore the result of the expansion.

So, you should now be able to understand the following sequence:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
$ echo me*
me*
$ touch me
$ echo me*
me
$ echo [a]
[a]
$ echo [abcd]
[abcd]
$ >a
$ ls -l 
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ljm ljm 0 May 31 18:40 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ljm ljm 0 May 31 18:39 me
$ echo [abcd]
a
$ echo [b]
[b]
```